# Compare text value with the excel value

Tags: selenium-ide

I am trying to write an automated script using selenium (Java/JUnit4/Remote Control). Here is the scenario.

I need to verify the value present in textbox with the value present in excel sheet. And if the value matches then test step should pass else fail.

Comment: I dont think the ide would support excel sheet interaction.  You need to start utilizing webdriver

Comment: see this link http://learnseleniumautomation.blogspot.ie/2012/03/reading-writing-from-excel-files-for.html - might help. you'll have to adjust to your needs

Comment: Can I read the value using selenium.getValue("xpath=id('confirmEmailAddress')"); and then saving it into some variable. kindly let me know hwow to do that... Secondly, I know how to read data from excel but dont know how to compare the data from excel with the data stored in variable.